# Как создать пакет в WMathematica с приватными функциями?

Tags: mathematica

Не могу разобраться с контекстными, при создании пакета. 
Необходимо создать пакет с перечнем функций. Внутри пакета нужны служебные функции. Для этого использую внутренний контекст. 
`Begin[]; End[]`

Однако при подключении пакета, функции пакета "не видят" внутренние функции. Попробовал использовать указатель контекста, это проблему не решило.

Однако когда подключаешь пакет повторно, все работает. В чем ошибка?

P.S. Набросал пример, для демонстрации проблемы.

Код пакета:

```
BeginPackage["P`"];

Begin["`Pr`"];

pB[b_]:=b^3;

End[];

pA[a_]:=a^2;
pC[c_]:=pB[c]^4;
pD[d_]:=Pr`pB[d]+Pr`pB[d];

EndPackage[];
```

Код блокнота:

```
$ContextPath

{"WolframAlphaClient`", "StreamingLoader`", "InterpreterLoader`", \
"IconizeLoader`", "HTTPHandlingLoader`", "CloudObjectLoader`", \
"PacletManager`", "System`", "Global`"}

(*Вызывается первый раз*)
<< (NotebookDirectory[] <> "P.wl")
$ContextPath

{"P`", "WolframAlphaClient`", "StreamingLoader`", \
"InterpreterLoader`", "IconizeLoader`", "HTTPHandlingLoader`", \
"CloudObjectLoader`", "PacletManager`", "System`", "Global`"}

(*Первая попытка использовать функции*)
pA[6]

pC[4]
pD[4]

36

pB[4]^4

2 Pr`pB[4]

(*Вызывается второй раз*)
<< (NotebookDirectory[] <> "P.wl")
$ContextPath

{"P`", "WolframAlphaClient`", "StreamingLoader`", \
"InterpreterLoader`", "IconizeLoader`", "HTTPHandlingLoader`", \
"CloudObjectLoader`", "PacletManager`", "System`", "Global`"}

(*Вторая попытка использовать функции*)
pA[6]

pC[4]
pD[4]

36

16777216

2 Pr`pB[4]
```

P.P.S. Прикладываю скрины файлов.

- [Блокнот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FAM4.png)
- [Пакет](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30jPN.png)

Comment: И, что Вам помешало приложить сами тексты вместо скриншотов?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov не видно какие ячейки Input, а какие Output